# can't remove event listener from JavaScript element

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I am having trouble removing the following event listener once it has been set:

```
videoTimeline = document.querySelectorAll(".video-timeline")

const draggableProgressBar = e => function(el) {
        let timelineWidth = e.clientWidth;
        e.closest(".container").querySelector(".progress-bar").style.width = `${el.offsetX}px`;
        e.closest(".container").querySelector("video").currentTime = (el.offsetX / timelineWidth) * e.closest(".container").querySelector("video").duration;
        e.closest(".container").querySelector(".current-time").innerText = formatTime(e.closest(".container").querySelector("video").currentTime);

    }

videoTimeline.forEach(el => 
        el.addEventListener("mousedown", () => el.addEventListener("mousemove", draggableProgressBar(el)))
    );

document.addEventListener("mouseup", () =>
        videoTimeline.forEach(el => 
            el.removeEventListener("mousemove", draggableProgressBar(el))
        )
    );
```

the event listener is added and works perfectly but doesn't get removed.

I've tried looping through to remove the event listener the same way it is applied but nothing works.

My question was marked as a duplicate linked to an answer that doesn’t solve my problem. Can you not do this until my problem is solved.

Comment: Because you are passing a new function to `removeEventListener` instead of the one you passed to the `addEventListener`

Comment: @Konrad plz check again, the same function is passed.

Comment: @MarcusWright `() => {}` is a new function, which you create every time. Example: `(() => {}) !== (() => {}) ` - two different functions!

Comment: @MarcusWright "My question was marked as a duplicate linked to an answer that doesn’t solve my problem. Can you not do this until my problem is solved" it is a duplicate and the other does solve your problem. Functions are objects and `{} !== {}` because objects are compared by *referential equality*. If you have `let foo = {}; let bar = {};` and then do `foo.a = 3;` would you expect `bar` to be modified? No, because those are two different objects. It's the same thing with your callbacks.